# Associate a Jbutton with object values of an ArrayList. Swing

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a mahjong project.
My code contains a dynamic `List<List<Tiles>>` board.
The abstract class Tiles gets extended by the different kind of Tiles the game has.
Now im interesting on extending this small project with GUI componenets.

My thinking is to create the grid with a GridBagLayout cause my Array is dynamic sized.

A simmilar question has been asked in the past but i had hard time understanding anything from the answers and its a bit old also. [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40017533/assigning-values-to-jbuttons-from-object-arraylist)

What i need is: when im creating an array of Jbuttons i want uponcreation of each button to place inside of them the info of each cell of the array.

Here is for example what my board array looks like: (one cell example)

```
specialvalue= 1x
coordinates = {0,0}
colour = blue
```

how i can hold this information in a Jbutton ? 
And if its not possible , whats the best way to go from here?

Thanks in advance, 
I can post some code of the project upon needed.

Comment: `how i can hold this information in a Jbutton ?` - extend the JButton and add custom properties to your custom class.

Comment: @camickr i think im getting where u want me to but im not really sure i understand 100%, can you clarify a bit please mate?

Comment: @camickr That's a surprisingly bad advice. It sounds like a horrible way of mixing the View and the Model. In most cases, it should be sufficient to know the *coordinates* of the tile that a certain button represents, and this can usually be solved by setting up a proper listener. Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/a/53199318/3182664 could help, although it's not perfectly spot-on for *this specific* question.

Comment: @Marco13 `it should be sufficient to know the coordinates of the tile` - not sure what you are suggesting?

Comment: @camickr Now, a button is a UI element, and should *not* be used to store any of the game state (or the model, so to speak). Whether or not you use `JButton` instances or painting your own tiles (via `graphics.drawImage`) should not matter for the game at all. What matters is: When the button (or more generally: the visual representation of the tile) is clicked, then something should happen. And determining *which* tile was clicked can be done by passing the (x,y) coordinates of the tile to a listener.

Comment: @Marco13 can you provide an example please?

Comment: @Marco13, `a button is a UI element,` the extended button is used in the implementation of the view.  `When the button (or more generally: the visual representation of the tile) is clicked, then something should happen` - agreed. I'm no MVC expert, but as far as I know the view now translates that "click" and updates the model. So the view needs to know the row/column that was clicked so it can invoke a "cellClicked(row, column)" method of the view so the view can then update its state. I equate this to something like clicking on a cell of a JTable.

Comment: This conversion is hidden in the view. If the view decides to use real components, then the view can get the row/column from the extended JButton. If the view paints the tiles. then the view will need to do some math to convert the mouse click to a an actual cell.

Comment: `i think im getting where u want me to but im not really sure i understand 100%` - all I am suggesting is you extend JButton and add a few properties with getter/setter methods to keep the extra information you need.

Comment: @camickr There are different flavors and specializations (and tbh: interpretations) of the MVC. The "thing that translates the click into a model change" is rather the Controller ... [it's difficult](http://wiki.c2.com/?WhatsaControllerAnyway), but for Swing, I think that every (even anonymous) Listener is a small Controller. The point is: In a perfect World, you'd be able to play the game at the command line, without any GUI. In any case, let's hope that the asker never wants to switch from `JButton` to `JLabel` objects (or to custom painting) - that'll be quite some refactoring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i come back to my question i see that there was never an exact answer so here is how i did it at last and worked.
I used an abstract class for the Tiles , then i created a hashmap at my GUI class and i made key-value pairs with keys:jbuttons and values: all the info of Tiles i needed.

That was the main key to the solution.